# Adding many actors to the stage

Tags: optimization, libgdx, actor, stage

I crating project to play with some sort of simulation. So i create map, this map is actually grid with cells, each cell is 2 actors - 1 background and 1 icon that show cell  type - forest, mountain, person and etc.

Here how it looks:

[image]

All works just fine, but when i try to increase cells from 20x20 to 100x100 it takes about 20-30 seconds to load. It doesn't seems lags after it loads, so it works just fine, but now question - is there a way to optimize loading time, or it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Todays systems should be able to handle as little as 100x100 cells. I guess your problem is somewhere in your code.

Some common mistakes are:

- Creating new objects in your render method (with the "new" keyword) instead of reusing your objects
- Loading your images everytime you render them

Maybe you can add some code of your render method to the question. Without any code it's hard to see the problem.